# Can google cloud functions listen to multiple event triggers?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I am currently trying to deploy a Google cloud function using the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions#resource-cloudfunction), in order to listen to a Google cloud storage bucket for changes/deletions.

However, I noticed that I can only specify one `EventTrigger`

```
{
  "name": string,
  "description": string,
  "status": enum (CloudFunctionStatus),
  "entryPoint": string,
  "runtime": string,

  ...

  "sourceUploadUrl": string
  // End of list of possible types for union field source_code.

  // Union field trigger can be only one of the following:
  "httpsTrigger": {
    object (HttpsTrigger)
  },
  "eventTrigger": {
    object (EventTrigger)
  }
  // End of list of possible types for union field trigger.
}
```

With my options for what to listen to being the following [choices](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage)

- `google.storage.object.finalize`
- `google.storage.object.delete`
- `google.storage.object.archive`
- `google.storage.object.metadataUpdate`

What if I want to listen to multiple triggers, such as `google.storage.object.finalize` and `google.storage.object.delete`, at the same time? Do I need to deploy separate cloud functions for each one? That seems quite inconvenient. Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you need to deploy multiple functions. Each function can have exactly one trigger.

You could deploy multiple configurations that use the same sources, or use one trigger which has a response to call another function that aggregates different kinds of events.

Comment: Paul - add a link to your answer. This will help others.

Comment: @JohnHanley The link is in the question.  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions#resource-cloudfunction

Answer (score 4):

It can be actually achieved, we do so in our company.

**The trick is: put your Cloud Function / Cloud Run as only-authenticated http trigger**

Then you get a URL (which only can be touched via authenticated http request).

Then you can both:

- Invoke it directly (postman / whatever) if you pass the Bearer token (i.e. get via gcloud auth print-identity-token)
- Trigger from **pubsub** with a PUSH subscription authenticated to that endpoint.

Note that it requires you to give permission from your PubSub subscriber to that resource, but it works! and makes your function/service both sync and async behaviour.

Comment: This sounds like an absolute nightmare to maintain if scaled to more complex setups.

Comment: This answer should be added to the "Shooting yourself in the foot in various programming languages" list: http://www.toodarkpark.org/computers/humor/shoot-self-in-foot.html :-S

Answer (score 3):

Paul answer is correct if you want to handle only a subset of available events. Or if you want to want to plug directly function on storage events.

However, if you want to catch all, or if you want to choose yourselves in your function the events type to handle, you can 'cheat'.

Indeed, you can [publish bucket notification in pubsub](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reporting-changes), and [plug a function on pubsub events](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub).