# A trigger function used by many buckets in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to write an function which can be used by all the buckets and what lead to this situation is when have so many dirty data in the old bucket for testing I want to create an new one but I still want to keep the old bucket for testing like dev, test, staging environment purpose and so on. I currently have 3 buckets and they require the same onFinalize trigger. I don't want to write the same function 3 times in my index.js file, is there any way to to do this ?

I did try to read the document but I have no found any possible solution to this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to deploy three different functions for three different buckets.  Each bucket generates a different series of events.  You are free to share the same implementation code among them though.

See also:

- [Can google cloud functions listen to multiple event triggers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57632786/can-google-cloud-functions-listen-to-multiple-event-triggers)
- [Is it possible to create one Firebase Storage trigger and apply it on all buckets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75460790/is-it-possible-to-create-one-firebase-storage-trigger-and-apply-it-on-all-bucket)

Comment: Thanks Doug, very helpful information